# How to access role property of userdata which is on mock json server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

This is my Json data

```
{
  "LoginData": [
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "password": "123",
      "role": "employee"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ratan",
      "password": "123",
      "role": "manager"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rahul",
      "password": "123",
      "role": "admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

By using filer method with name i get specific data and stored it in variable userData

[{name: 'Rahul', password: '123', role: 'admin'}]

But i cannot access its role using userData.role it gives undefined

what change should i do so that it gives me userData.role === "admin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), `Array#filter` returns:

> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

Therefore, you need to access the first element in the returned array first:

```js
const data = {
  "LoginData": [
    { "name": "Nick", "password": "123", "role": "employee" },
    { "name": "Ratan", "password": "123", "role": "manager" },
    { "name": "Rahul", "password": "123", "role": "admin" }
  ]
}

const userData = data.LoginData.filter(({ name }) => name === 'Rahul');
const role = userData[0]?.role;

console.log(role);
```

If there's always max one item matching, [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would be better here:

```js
const data = {
  "LoginData": [
    { "name": "Nick", "password": "123", "role": "employee" },
    { "name": "Ratan", "password": "123", "role": "manager" },
    { "name": "Rahul", "password": "123", "role": "admin" }
  ]
}

const userData = data.LoginData.find(({ name }) => name === 'Rahul');
const role = userData?.role;

console.log(role);
```

Comment: Thanks, both methods works but yes find looked better

Answer (score 1):

When you use `filter` function, you get `array` in output. You should consider using `find` method.

Also, I would recommend you to learn about array methods on MDN Docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array